# postfix Relay access denied for one mail address

Tags: postfix, email-server, vps, centos7

I have a vps (Centos 7) with several domains and emails. I'm using Postfix/Dovecot for send/receive email. Everything works fine but the last email for one doamin. I get this error (form /var/log/maillog) :

```
Sep  6 09:54:19 mail postfix/smtpd[4227]: 9F1D820EE6A6: reject: RCPT from unknown[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: 454 4.7.1 <RECIPIENT>: Relay access denied; from=<SENDER> to=<RECIPIENT> proto=ESMTP helo=<PCNAME>
```

Can anybody help me?

**EDIT**

These are the lines that I think relates to the problem:

```
smtpd_relay_restrictions = permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, defer_unauth_destination
relay_domains = $mydestination
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
```

Comment: You would have to post the relevant portions of your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file (everything related to relaying, recipient restrictions, sender restrictions, etc.) and any map files that are referenced in those relevant portions of the config file.

Comment: Sorry, there was a misconfiguration in mail client. It now works correctly.